# LaTeX chemformula in header

Tags: packages, bold, section-titles, chemformula

For my thesis, I'd like to add a mchem formula to the title of a chapter. However, I cannot manage LaTeX to print it in bold. Here is the package I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{article}
\usepackage[version=1]{mhchem}
\subsection{\ce{He^+} on Enstatite (\ce{MgSiO_3})}
```

[image]

This is the output I'm getting, although I would like it to be uniformly bold. I have already tried to put a \textbf in front of the \ce expressions but that didn't work. I am grateful for any help I can get on this!

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly set `version=1` as a package option, which forces `mhchem` to use math mode for all text. That quite deliberately does not follow surrounding (text) font changes. I would strongly suggest using the latest version: `version=4`. You can then also omit the `_` in the input for `MgSiO3`.

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, if I use versions 2,3 or 4 of mhchem the "+" next to "He" is displayed differently, it gets bigger. Is there any way to keep the small plus and still have LaTeX print the formula in bold?

Comment: @bcserven The only change I can see is that the `+`, like the other symbols, now follows the surrounding font change. That's by-design, but you could force math mode for the `+`: `\cs{He^{$+$}}`.